# Java Selenium WebDriverWait waits longer than specified wait

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I don't understand what's happening with the newer version of Selenium's `WebDriverWait` but as far as I can see, it's not behaving the way I'd expect it to.

I have tried all the versions from `4.0.0-beta-1` - `4.0.0-beta-4` and I have just updated to `4.0.0-beta-4` as my preferred version.

I use these methods in my own functions:

```
isPresent
isVisible
isClickable
```

Each of them have their respective constructors that they call:

```
WebDriverWait Presence = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
WebDriverWait Visible = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofMillis(1L));
WebDriverWait Clickable = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofMillis(1L));
```

A couple of things that I found:

1. The old constructors would accept their time durations provided as type `Long` and in seconds
2. The new constructors accept their time durations provided as type `Duration`
3. `Duration` has it's own methods which accept type `Long`

Previously, you could write it like this:

```
WebDriverWait Presence = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 1L);
```

Now, it looks like this (*as shown above*):

```
WebDriverWait Presence = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
```

The only difference being how you define the wait.

With using `Duration`, you can specify the "type":

```
Duration.ofDays(1L)
Duration.ofHours(1L)
Duration.ofMinutes(1L)
Duration.ofSeconds(1L)
Duration.ofMillis(1L)
Duration.ofNanos(1L)
```

In my above code example, I define the `WebDriverWait` using the `Duration.ofSeconds(1L)`, meaning it should wait for just 1 second, however, it waits for *10 seconds instead*.

In fact, it waits for 10 seconds whether it's set to `Duration.ofMillis` or `Duration.ofNanos` too.

So, either I really don't understand the implementation correctly, or there's something I am missing, or there's an issue with the actual `WebDriverWait` class.

It's also worth mentioning, it doesn't wait 10 seconds whether the `WebElement` exists or not, it only waits the full duration if the `WebElement` does NOT exist.

Hoping someone can assist with this.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening with the newer version of Selenium's  - which version you are referring ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Oh right! Probably a good idea to include that lol.. I have updated my question with the version I am using. :) But for reference here, I am using `4.0.0-beta-3`

Comment: I hope you do not mix WebDriverWait with implicitlyWait and have no some kind of global WebDriverWait  mixed with local WebDriverWait ?

Comment: @Prophet Thank you for the reply. I do not have any other waits that I have explicitly implemented. Up to the point of the `WebDriverWait` implementation, there's nothing else that's been defined/specified.

Comment: It's says it's beat version, you cannot rely on beta can you ?

Comment: @cruisepandey 100% agree. It's definitely a thought that crossed my mind, however there's always the chance I have done/implemented something incorrectly and that could have been what's going wrong. So rather than assume, I'd just ask for help and see if the community is able to advise. :)

Comment: @EitelDagnin : I acknowledge.